# JOptionPane interfers with ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

I have an exam in few days and I have a problem.

I have made a program that uses an Action Listener on a JButton to open a JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog

But when I press Yes on the CofirmDialog it triggers my ActionListener again and act as if we had clicked on the Jbutton so we enter the loop again that open the ConfirmDialog.

I have tried everything. Here is my actionlistener. I previously added my listener in my code.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent bb) {
    
    if (bb.getSource().equals(Detruire)) {

        String REF = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quel produit  : ");
        
        for(int k=0;k<ListeProduit1.size();k++ ) {
            if(ListeProduit1.get(k).getRef().equals(REF)) {
                
                LocalDate aujourdhui = LocalDate.now(); 
                
                if (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(aujourdhui,ListeProduit1.get(k).getExpiration())<0){
                    
                    int input =JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Attention le produit est périmé de : "+ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(ListeProduit1.get(k).getExpiration(),aujourdhui)+" jours. Voulez-vous le supprimer ? ","Attntion",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if(input==0) {
                        ListeProduit1.remove(k);
                        frame1.dispose();
                        
                    }
                }
                else {
                    int input1 =JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Attention le produit est encore bon. Jours avant expiration : "+ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(aujourdhui,ListeProduit1.get(k).getExpiration())+" jours. Voulez-vous le supprimer ? ","Attntion",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if(input1==0) {
                        ListeProduit1.remove(k);
                        frame1.dispose();
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
        }
    }
```

I used in my code before :

```
JButton Detruire = new JButton("Detruire");
Detruire.addActionListener(this);
```

To conclude, this problem happens when I click on the button a second time.

Comment: 1) Don't add code in the comments. Edit your question with the updated code so all the information related to your question is in one place. 2)  Why would you have a "for loop'" if you only want to display the confirm dialog once?

Comment: @camickr I enter in a "for loop" bc I am looking for a specific restaurant in an Array List of restaurant. The for is just here to search in this list for the good restaurant (using the number)

Comment: Maybe you added the ActionListener to the button twice or maybe you have two restaurants that meet your criteria? Do some debugging. The JOptionPane has nothing to do with the ActionListener. There is no way we can answer the question with the given invormation. Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem if you need more help. That is create a frame with a JButton, that displays a JOptionPane. Get that working first then fix your real application.

Comment: I have a question @camickr. If the class that builds the Jframe is called a second time without stopping the programm. Does the actionlistner is added twice ?

Comment: An application should only ever create a JFrame once. If you need child windows then you use a JDialog. If you create a new dialog and add a new button to the dialog, then the ActionListener is only added to the newly created button so it should only be added once. But who knows what your code looks like? Maybe you are using static variables, in which case the component will only be created once and then you would add the ActionListener multiple times.. The issue will be with the structure of your code. Without an MRE we can't help.